# End frame setting not respected after Time Remapping

Tags: rendering

this community has helped me countless times as a search reference. But this time I need to ask you for help.

Using evee, I created a 100 frames camera animation, through a pointcloud geometry nodes object. The camera moves along a path with constraints.
This felt too fast and not smooth enough. So I did the following:

- Change fps from 24 to 60 to address the smoothness (at least 2x slower).
- set time remap from 100 to 400 (4x slower, right?)
- increase the length by setting endframe from 100 to 800 frames (compensate for roughly double frame used in fps and time remap, so 100*2*4=800?)

Expected result:Slower and smoother animation consisting of 800 frames.

Actual result: Slower and smoother animation, cut off after 100 frames.

Problem: Blender stops rendering after 100 frames, the original length. No matter how long I set the animation. I also tried different remapping values. It will always stop rendering after 100

Any help welcome, thanks in advance.

[image]

It always stops after 100 frames of rendering:

[image]

Troubleshooting done so far:

- play around with different endframe and time remap values: no effect on number of frames rendered.
- Disable motion blur: no effect on number of frames rendered
- Tried overwrite disabled: no effect on number of frames rendered

Blender 2.93 LTS on macOS 10.15

Comment: please upload your blend file so we can check it out...and i don't know why you need that remapping. "normally" you would just render it, and if it is too fast, you would use the video editor and add speed control and adjust it as you need it!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Maybe I misunderstood time remapping, what I want is more frames across the same animation, to get a smoother result. I used time remapping in another project before to achieve this. Also, what is the best way to upload my .blend here?

Comment: Open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: ok, if i understood you right, your geometry nodes object is not animating, just the camera? why don't you just move the camera slower? so just double your frames and move your camera keyframes accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If you have a camera animation with constraints, you have something like this:

[image]

To make your animation slower/smoother, just select your curve which the camera follows and in "Path animation" just raise the frames number (e.g. if you double it, your animation will be half as fast.)

[image]

i would NOT change fps. I would not use remap. That way it is just easy to handle and to understand. Of course you have to increase your endframe with the same factor as you increased the frames.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I guess I was a bit over my head learning all those techniques at once. I already did that and the evaluation time was set to 500. I guess the render behaviour is a time remap bug. I will verify it in with another project and then file it if confirmed. In any case your recomendation to avoid remapping seems to be valid. I thought it is an easy way to avoid a lot of manual keying, turns out to be a headache factor ;) Thanks a million @Chris for your tireless help, learned a lot from your replies on this forum.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround:

1. Reset time remapping to 100/100.
2. Select all the objects to see and select their keyframes in the dopesheet, make sure you are on frame 0 and do keycombination s, 8.
   This worked for the camera animation.

Unfortunately there seems to be a bug and I had to select each bone individually and do an s,8 to spread the keyframes of my pose animation.

Afterwards it was only the usual segfaults and malloc interuptions. All in all i only had to restart the render from different frame positions